# Random ARP requests from source IP of different/nonexisting network

Tags: arp

I saw this in wireshark and it worries me a bit:
[image: 1]

My network is 192.168.178.0/24.

I already tried to look up the vendor from the MAC, no results.

Why does it lookup what seems to be random IPs and where are the packets coming from?

Any ideas?

Comment: You should examine the MAC table of your switch which port that MAC is connected to. Then you just follow the cable.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a host with a bad network mask and/or no gateway set. There is a single address from which the requests are sourced (`192.168.0.254`), but the destinations for many of the the requests are outside the network.

Answer (score 1):

The source MAC in question is ea-08-6b-aa-03-cb. (In case people cannot see the image)

I guess by now if you haven't ruled out @Ron Maupin suggestion you could see some ideas below:

> *Any ideas?*

- Confirm how often does this issue occur? If this was a one time issue, it's gone be harder to track down with such limited information.
- How far down on your network can you track this request being done? In case you have multiple gateways whether it's a single or multiple ISP's.
- Was this capture done on an Edge device, a host or server? Unless you don't already know. This for better understanding, approach in troubleshooting would be different.
- Try to confirm any type of MAC spoofing?. As there isn't much information about your network, you could perhaps think that a user (whether intended or not) is hiding it's MAC maybe for example as a recognizance attack. If that is so, what measures do you have in place to prevent it, i.e: user requires admin rights to do changes on PC.
- Confirm for any recent security audits? Reason for this is that Pen testing tools can run many different types of scans.
- Check what IP owns that MAC. Some ideas [here](https://superuser.com/questions/29640/inverse-arp-lookup):
- Check statistics? It sounds unlikely to be a DDOS broadcast storm attack.
- Besides the non exist network ARP requests, check any other interesting/suspicious traffic that you could correlate.

Using the following OUI lookup webpage nothing came up.
http://www.whatsmyip.org/mac-address-lookup/

I did a manual lookup as well in ieee just to crosscheck information, however this is only for public addressing.
http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt

More exhaustive lookup by checking:

https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf

From the sample of addresses in the image you provided(omitting 192 range), only one points to a goverment address:
Name:  sirius.mcs.anl.gov
Address:  140.221.8.88

158.121.104.4: Non-existent domain
216.133.140.77: Non-existent domain

66.243.43.2
DNS request timed out.
timeout was 2 seconds.

If you test it out the domain sirius.mcs.anl.gov is not available to public it seems, it will time out when trying to reach with your browser. If you are what some would consider a 'paranoid' engineer, this could mean a red flag.